# How do I position a imageButton inside of a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

Im working on adding a visibility icon for the password field. I want the icon positioned to the right of the password text. But when I put the image button inside the `TextInputLayout` it forces the button to be below the password field. I am unable to put in on the right of it.

**Here is the structure of the activity**

[image: Activity]([![acitivityDesign]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ole_logo" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="@string/system_name"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/app_version"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@color/bg_white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1">

                <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/syncIcon"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnSetting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyAppTheme.TextInputLayout">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/input_name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/MyAppTheme.TextInputLayout">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/bg_white"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/visibilityicon" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/input_password"
                            android:layout_width="248dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/save"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:alpha="0.7"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:text="Save Username and Password"
                        android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_dark_background"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please paste your `xml` file

Comment: Ok, it is added. TextInputLayout is near bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add separate view, you can set below properties of `TextInputLayout` to enable password visibility toggle.

```
app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/another_toggle_drawable"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

Comment: I need it to be a clickable button, thats why it is a imageButton

Comment: Yes, is there another way to do that without imageButton?

Comment: set the properties I have mentioned, there will be icon visible to toggle the visibility of password.

Comment: The drawable does not display properly. It has a transparency and only shows a shadow

Comment: *is there another way to do that without imageButton?* Yes remove your `ImageButton` and follow the answer @inDepth

Comment: Yes, I followed the answer. But did not get expected results

Comment: It does toggle visibility, but the image does not show how it should

Comment: please add color using this line `app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorAccent"` or add any other dark color hope it's show batter

Comment: Hmm, only shows shadow of drawable.. perhaps I should ask as another question

Comment: make sure you are are using correct png image. or you can add it from android studio.

Comment: you can add it from new -> image assets -> action bar and tab icons and select the icon from available ones.

Comment: Yea its a PNG that was exported from adobe illustrator.

Comment: try with one of the icon from android studio and see if they look fine, then you might need to change some properties of your illustrator icon and can use it again.

Comment: new problem, icon shows in layout, but not when I run it in emulator

Comment: Working after `invalidate cache and restart`